# Spring autowired TaskExecutor executed tasks returns null, how is it possible to fix?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, rest

I have an application, that needs to load entities in JSON format, then i need to add it to some Collection

When i try to load entites in a main thread, everyhthings works fine, but if i try to load them using Spring TaskExecutor, load method throws NullPointerException:

> Cannot invoke
> "org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(String,
> org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,
> org.springframework.http.HttpEntity,
> org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference, Object[])"
> because "this.restTemplate" is null

I guess this happens because of missing autowired dependency injection when its used by TaskExecutor, but i have injected TaskExecutor bean.

What could be reason of this issue?
Thanks a lot! Have a nice day!

Here is communication class that works with RestTemplate

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate     

public Article getArticle(int id){
    final String URL = "here is API url" + id;
    ResponseEntity<Article> responseEntity;
    try {
        responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Article>() {
        });
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException ex){
    return null;
    }
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

Here is main logic class

```
    @Autowired
    Communication communication;
    @Autowired
    ArticleService articleService;
    @Autowired
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    static List<Article> inMemoryArticles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void loadMultipleArticles(int start, int limit) {
        int tasksCount = limit;
        int threadsCount = 4;

        int firstID = communication.getFirstArticleID(start);


        for(int i = firstID; i <= firstID+tasksCount; i++){
                       taskExecutor.execute(new LoaderThread(i));
            }
        
    }

}
```

and here is Thread class

```
class LoaderThread implements Runnable{
    Communication communication = new Communication();
    private int id;
    public LoaderThread(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (Logic.inMemoryArticles) {
            Logic.inMemoryArticles.add(communication.getArticle(id));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I guess this happens because of missing autowired dependency injection
> when its used by TaskExecutor, but i have injected TaskExecutor bean.

Yes, but the `RestTemplate` you are trying to autowire is null because Spring doesn't provides a single auto-configured RestTemplate bean, there the error. A possible solution is included in the [spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) guide, where it has been annotated with `Bean` a method returning a `RestTemplate` that can be included in a `Configuration` annotated class or equivalent mechanism:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
}
```